# Margin on all content pages in Template10 XAML

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I am using Template10 with the Hamburger starting project template.  I'd like to have a margin between the hamburger area on the left and all content.  I tried changing the shared Shell.xaml page (by adding a margin, etc.) but couldn't figure out the best way to sort it out.  Conceptually, that makes sense, but it's the specific detail of how to make it work that I'm missing.

Is there an easy way to do it without changing each content page?

Regarding the questions in the comments: I want it in the closed case of a wide view; the question doesn't make any sense in any other case.  As far as what I tried, it doesn't really ultimately matter, since none of what I tried worked - I'm asking what the right way is to do it, which I never figured out.

Here's what the default looks like, without a margin:

[image: view with no margin]
Here's what it looks like with a margin added to the content area, which is also how the sample template contents handle this:

[image: view with margin]

I don't want to have to mark up every content page with left margins to get the offset in the second picture.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMA10.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUIuO.png

Comment: Never used it but I would assume there's a parent view where the content views are presented? Maybe that's Shell.xaml you mention? I'd just slap a Margin on that content presenter and be done with it. :)

Comment: Shell should be the only place to make the change.

Comment: I've clarified that I understand that Shell.xaml makes the most sense, but I don't know how to actually change it to get a proper margin into it.

Comment: Too little information. When the Hamburger Menu is in which Display Mode? What *exactly* did you try? Why *exactly* didn't it work for you? What *exactly* are you wanting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now I have enough information. You have a few options here. The first is just bite the bullet like the rest of the developer community and format your pages like normal. But if you simply must, you can create an implicit `Page` style with a setter setting `Margin="16,16,16,16"` but, listen, and I am not kidding, you will ultimately regret it unless your app is super-simple. The biggest problem will be the spacing will be OUTSIDE the containing `ScrollViewer`.

Thanks for using Template 10.

Comment: ok, so I guess the short version is, what I'm asking for, isn't really possible.  That sucks.  But since you're the one to be able to say for sure either way, I'm accepting the answer, since I'm assuming it's correct.